# Server sent event, how many event source can i create

Tags: javascript, php, database, server-sent-events

I have a database containing users details, then listing them separately in a page.
I am using the server sent event to call them. But each time i am initializing. Is it right to do so?

```
if (!!window.EventSource) {
        var source = new EventSource("get_vacation_days.php");
    } else {
        alert("Your browser does not support Server-sent events! Please upgrade it!");
    }
    source.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
        getVacationDays(e.data);
    }, false);

    source.addEventListener("open", function(e) {
        console.log("Connection was opened.");
    }, false);
    source.addEventListener("error", function(e) {
        console.log("Error: " );
        console.log(e);
    }, false);
```

And the next data:

```
if (!!window.EventSource) {
    var source = new EventSource("get_days_in_company.php");
} else {
    alert("Your browser does not support Server-sent events! Please upgrade it!");
}
source.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
    getDaysInCompany(e.data);
}, false);
source.addEventListener("open", function(e) {
    console.log("Connection was opened.");
}, false);

source.addEventListener("error", function(e) {
    console.log("Error: " );
    console.log(e);
}, false);
```

Comment: That code looks fine (assuming it is being run just once each time the page loads), but I wasn't sure what "But each time i am initializing" meant. Does "each time" refer to each time your PHP script pushes out a new message, or each time the html page is loaded? And what is "initializing"? The EventSource object, or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have multiple EventSource, the only limitation is how hard you want to work your client's browser and how many open connections your infrastructure can handle.